# Rails 3 development environment keeps caching, even without caching on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

i have a `rails` 3 app in dev mode that won't load any changes i make when its running webrick.  i triple checked the settings for my `development.rb` and made sure i am running in development mode.

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

i also checked my `tmp` directory to make sure the cache folder is empty - i have yet to do any caching on the site and have never turned on caching.  im guessing its a loading problem with the files.

also i was running on `webrick` then installed mongrel and the problem still persists.

im guessing ive run into a config problem, bc i dont see anyone else posting such a prob.  anything else im missing?

EDIT: it looks like my view helpers aren't auto loadable - aren't helpers by default supposed to be reloadable in rails 3?

Comment: do you use STI on your project ;)

Comment: @fl00r, I know I'm a little late to the game here, but could you elaborate on that point?

Comment: If you're using STI in development you should autoload (cache) classes or inheritance won't work properly

Comment: did you ever find and answer to this?

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar experience, but I don't believe it was with an actual helper class, it was with anything I wrote under the `lib/` directory. If you've had to use a `require 'some_class'` statement, then you should switch it to:

```
require_dependency 'some_class'
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and here is the simple solution.
In your `config/environments/development.rb` set following settings:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.perform_caching = false
config.cache_store = :null_store
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone coming here with a similar issue, make sure you didn't accidentally move `production.rb` from `config/environments/` to `config/initializers/` like I did. That will make Rails read in the `production.rb` file and override your development settings. Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, it was caused by rails-dev-tweaks gem which is, if you used default configuration from README, disabling stack reload upon AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails 4, and my cache call was in a helper using `Rails.cache.fetch`.

After googling a bit, I found out this issue (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20733), where a PR was merged into rails 5 documentation to make clear that '

> Changing the value of config.action_controller.perform_caching will
>   only have an effect on the caching provided by the Action Controller
>   component. For instance, it will not impact low-level caching, that we
>   address below.

', being 'low-level-caching' the Rails.cache.fetch.

It's on the docs now: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html