# Caching evaluated result in rails helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When implementing some helper methods, sometimes, I want to store some computed result somewhere accessible from the helper method as a cache.

If I store it into instance variable, it will pollute instances, so it looks like not wise to do that.

Any good place to store such value?
Or doing such heavy weight computing in a helper is a bad idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sometimes I use Rails cache to store this kind of values. The code is like this,

```
def helper_method
  Rails.cache.fetch('helper_value') do
    # calculate the value if it does not exist
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought use of cache is not what I expected but from the helper's point of view, this is the natural way to solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Just a tip: `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false` will NOT disable Rails.cache.fetch, only the regular ActionView `cache` helper. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43991463/1290457